# MySQL table synchronization : incomplete copy without error

Tags: mysql, sqlyog, unreliable-connection

I have used SQLYog community edition for a few months to copy almost daily a few dozens of tables from a production server to a development server, for testing purposes ("copy database"). It used to work correctly until last week. We noticed that lines were missing during the table copy, both with the last 32 bit version and with a former 64 bit version. Most errors occurred on the same two InnoDB tables, which have about 5.5 million lines each.
I was surprised to see MySQLYog didn't report any error. The bug is random. I found out that lines were missing when having a look at the results (sometimes only about 350 000 lines were copied, not even 10% of the data).

Has anybody faced the same problem in SQLYog?
It is getting worse and worse. This morning, I had to copy the same table 4 times in a row before getting the whole table.
In the end, we noticed in the MySQL logs that some communication packets had been lost. But why no error in the client? Why always on the same tables? It doesn't seem to be related to the content of the tables (the beginning of the tables hasn't changed).

We need help to transfer our data in a reliable way :
* Has anybody experienced communication packet losses with MySQL? Is there anything to change in MySQL configuration to make the transfer more reliable?
* Does anybody know a better free tool for quickly and reliably copying tables between servers?

Comment: During my use of SQLYog I noticed that it sometimes doesn't copy triggers, views, stored procedures and such and it doesn't produce any error of any sort. I have no clue how to fix it, but for data copy or data sync - I would never use it. I'd rather export the table(s) in question and manually import them to the other system, especially the ones with several millions of rows. Alternatively, since I am lazy, I'd create my own script that would do that for me.

Comment: Have you tried mysqldump through netcat? Something along these lines: On the server: `mysqldump -h localhost -p dbname | netcat clientmachine 7777` and on the client `netcat -l 7777 | mysql -u root -p dbname`. Crude but works. `| gzip` to taste